# HTML: contentEditable troubles

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

I have this simple HTML:

```
<html><body>
<input><div contenteditable="true" style="border:1px #7f9db9 solid; width:100px; height:20px;"></div>
</body></html>
```

It shows two input boxes. When I type something into the 2nd one, then go at the very beginning of the row (hit Home-key), then I hit Backspace, the text jumps at the end of the 1st input box... I run latest Firefox.

Why doesn't the text stay in its box, as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have `<input>`

Also -- you might try something like this instead:

```
<div id="editable" contentEditable="true"  >
    <span contentEditable="True" >Text to delete</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How could I delete the DIV? Besides, I just checked it with Node Inspector and it's still there..